# Is there a way to split interpolated strings over multiple lines in C# whilst executing the same at run time in terms of performance

Tags: c#, string, string-interpolation

I have been having some discussion with colleagues of the best way to format the following code.

```
return $" this is a really long string.{a} this is a really long string. this is a really long string. this is a really long string. this is a really long string. this is a really long string. this is a really long string. this is a really long string. this is a really long string. this is a really long string. this is a really long string. this is a really long string.{b} this is a really long string. this is a really long string. this is a really long string. this is a really long string. this is a really long string. this is a really long string.{c}";
```

My goto is: (newline on predesignated point ie around 80 chars)

```
return  $" this is a really long string.{a} this is a really long string. this is a really long string." +
        $" this is a really long string. this is a really long string. this is a really long string." +
        $" this is a really long string. this is a really long string. this is a really long string." +
        $" this is a really long string. this is a really long string. this is a really long string." +
        $"{b} this is a really long string. this is a really long string. this is a really long string." +
        $" this is a really long string. this is a really long string. this is a really long string.{c}";
```

However I'm worried that I'm adding unnecessary work at runtime. Is this the case?
If so is there a better way of doing it?

Also I don't find line-wrap to be a good answer ><

Comment: Compile this and examine the IL. I wouldn't be surprised if the compiler optimizes this to a single string. Hence, no run-time concatenations.

Comment: In that exact case I would imagine the compiler might optimise those concats out, of course it can't do that if you have any variables or formatting in there.

Comment: @wablab what is IL?

Comment: IL stands for **I**ntermediate **L**anguage, you can check out some more information about it here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language

Comment: @konkked thanks ill read up.

Comment: You have a performance question. What do your performance tests show? If you don't have performance tests and you are concerned about performance then **how will you know if your code is too slow or not?**

Comment: @keyboardP, that is string literals it does not apply to the interpolated strings introduce in C# 6

Comment: @konkked - Whoops you're right, I was thinking OP was writing this in the IDE at compile time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TLDR String.Format is being called for interpolation, so concatenating strings that are being interpolated means more calls to String.Format

## Let's look at the IL

To get a better idea of what is actually going on when you have these questions is good to check out the IL (Intermediate Language), which is what your code is compiled into to then run on the .NET runtime. You can use [ildasm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(v=vs.110).aspx) for inspecting IL of compiled .NET DLLs and EXEs.

### Concatenating Multiple Strings

So here you can see that behind the scenes, String.Format is being called for each of the concatenated strings.

[image: Concatenated strings]

### Using One Long String

Here you see that String format is only being called once, meaning if you're talking about performance this way would be slightly better.

[image: One string]

Comment: Nice analysis. Was this a debug or release build? Does it make a difference? Just wondering if this one of those things that gets optimized in release builds.

Comment: @wablab both were release builds